# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and Wifi hardblock on Lenovo Y700 (intel ac 8260)

Tags: 16.04, wireless, lenovo

Installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on Ideapad Y700 with Intel AC 8260.

Executing `rfkill list` result with Hard block on the Wlan.

Any good solution?

extra information:

```
BIOS: cdcn25ww, dmi: SDK0K17763
LENOVO_BI_IDEAPAD_BU_idea_FM_


08:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 [8086:24f3] (rev 3a)

subsystem: Inel Corporation Wireless 8260 [8086:1010]
Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
```

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of the terminal command `lspci -nnk | grep -A2 Network` and `rfkill list`? Thanks.

Comment: Please edit the question to add results from terminal for `sudo dmidecode | grep -i version`

Comment: @DavidFoerster the first command return no such file or directory for both A2 and Network. rfkill list says that Ideapad: Wireless LAN soft blocked: no Hard blocked: yes

Comment: @Jeremy31 Firmware version not given by running that command

Comment: I know it doesn't show firmware version, I want to see the DMI version of your laptop as I doubt it is just called Y700 and it is likely something like Lenovo ideapad Y700-???

Comment: @Jeremy31 yes, it is Lenovo.

Comment: The exact info is needed for the quirk Pilot6 refers to and the correct solution might be in a newer kernel.  The 4.4 kernel has the fix for the Lenovo ideapad Y700-17ISK, but the 4.8 kernel also has Lenovo ideapad Y700-15ISK and Lenovo ideapad Y700 Touch-15ISK fixed

Comment: @Jeremy31 BIOS: cdcn25ww, dmi: SDK0K17763

Comment: Try `sudo dmidecode | grep -i lenovo`

Comment: @Jeremy31 the only extra information beside Lenovo as Vendor and Manufacturer is SKU: LENOVO_BI_IDEAPAD_BU_idea_FM_

Comment: It seems you entered the 1st command incorrectly. Can you try again. Copy and past it this time. Also, could you please [edit] your post, when you want to add information? Especially file or program output [listings](/editing-help#code) (with the help of the `{}` button in the editor toolbar) will be much more readable there; alternatively you can use a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) for longer listings and include the link of your pastie in your question. Overall it’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.

Comment: @DavidFoerster thx, added all the information in the question.

Comment: You should probably dump the dmi info to a text file with `sudo dmidecode > dmidecode.txt`  Then double click on the dmidecode.txt and use search to find Lenovo or Y700 to find the exact code.  There was another model  added to the linux kernel Y700-15ACZ a few months ago

Comment: What about the output of `rfkill list`?

Answer (score 1):

Run in a terminal

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/ideapad.conf <<< "blacklist ideapad_laptop"
```

and reboot.

Comment: thanks, adding to blacklist worked. But how about the better fix using an updated kernel or update in the firmware for Linux any idea?

Comment: It is not related to firmware or drivers. A better fix is to patch the kernel with a model specific quirk.

Comment: It would be nice if they added a no_wifi_rfkill to the module parameters that when set to 1 would do `write_ec_cmd(priv->adev->handle, VPCCMD_W_RF, 1`